# How to go to second previous action in ASP:NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know that this redirects user to previous action :

```
return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

I want to know how I can redirect user to second previous action? I mean previous of the previous page. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not rely on the Referrer url being the previous action.

Http is inherently stateless. The Referrer property is not reliable and can be quite easily changed.

If you are using sessions to track your users, you should use the session state on the server to store the actions visited and  read it from the session when needed.

Read more about ASP.NET sessions. You can use sessions with anonymous unauthenticated users too, it doesn't just refer to users logging in.

Sessions are comonnly tracked through cookies or by passing the session id through the url each time a users clicks a link.

Find more information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx